# Add Custom button to a search result

Tags: custom-button, search-layout

I create a list button in contact object where I used a visualforce page for it. 
I added the button to the search layout, But in search result layout the button doesn't show up.
I am an administrator, so basically I have all access control.
Can someone help me if there is other required step to do to add a button to a search result layout?

Comment: Are search results displayed in VF page or is it a standard search?

Comment: no it is a standard search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot add list button on search layouts.